# Django Error: No FlatPage matches the given query

Tags: python, django

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

and

`(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),` is in `urls.py`.

What can I do to fix this error? Django is still displaying this error - I have googled and I can't find anything.

#### File urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'cms.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^cms/', include('cms.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),        
)
```

It's the most basic `urls.py`. That's why I didn't have to post the code, but here it is.

It is also enabled. Since this is a new project I'm going to show every file.

**_*init*_** is empty

#### settings.py

```
# Django settings for CMS project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\django-projects\cms/cms.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'o2lqxjp!fg%0xod5g$79alt_*o4&lkw-ncr^30iuqcv(y-44i7'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cms.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

And finally `manage.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

import settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

1. flatpages in the administrative interface work
2. I have actually added that page via the admin
3. this is the path to my database:

   C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\django-projects\cms\cms.db

And when I run `python manage.py syncdb`, I see no error.

1. I'm trying to access

   `http://localhost:8000/test/`
2. when I type `python manage.py runserver`, I see no error.

The admin interface works perfectly.

Comment: It'd help if you posted the code in urls.py, for starters.

Comment: And maybe your settings.py...did you enable the app?

Comment: @keith.layne please read my edit

Comment: What URL are you using to access when you get this error?  Does editing flatpages in the admin interface work?  Have you actually added that page via the admin?  It's hard to answer without knowing more info.  My previous answer was just an obvious failing on your part to *read the directions*.  How do we know what other directions you haven't followed?  Also, the path to your db mixes forward and backward slashes...is that causing any other problems?

Comment: @keith.layne please read my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is, you do not need an `urls.py` for `flatpages`. Instead, you need:

> Add 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware'
>   to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting.

This is quoted from the Django documentation, *[The flatpages application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/flatpages/)*.

After checking the code and the project, the problem was that in the `admin` when editing or creating a flatpage, you must select one or many sites to relate.

Comment: I added it this morning but i forgot to update the question - still does not work

Comment: How are you using flatpages? in what url you get the error? why are you adding a line to urls.py?

Comment: In the admin you put localhost:8000 in Sites?

Comment: I'm using flatpages to create a cms, i geet the error when i try to see the page that i added localhost:8000/test  ...what line am i adding to urls.py?

Comment: domain name is 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Why are you doing this: (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),? And you put localhost:8000 in Sites via admin?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5075/discussion-between-diegueus9-and-eli)

Comment: i added localhost:8000 instead of my ip - doesn't make any difference - if i remove (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')), i will see Using the URLconf defined in cms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, test/, didn't match any of these. and the 404 error

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the data you put in the flatpage via admin you sure you write '/test/' in the form?

Comment: yes i have added /test/ sorry i had an internet problem couldn't go to chat, my email is elieobeid7 at gmail we can chat tomorrow if you want and if you have teamviewer you can work on my pc

Answer (score 6):

I encounter the same problem when I was giving my hands to django flatpages.
The problem is your site ID.

When I try to add flatpage from admin site and adding a site to my flat page,
There is example.com in sites field which has SITE_ID=1(go through django_site table).

Example: I added a flat page using admin site with 
       **url = '/about/'
       site = "localhost:8000'
       name = "about"
       content = "This is about page"**

*If you are working on localhost, you will probably want to add localhost:8000 to your site.
Now This newly added site (localhost:8000) will have SITE_ID=2.*

You can verify this by browsing django_site table of your database you have mentioned in your setting file.

Now refer the **SITE_ID**(which is the primary key in **django_site** table) of localhost:8000 and edit you **SITE_ID** in setting file to point to this SITE_ID(i.e. SITE_ID of localhost:8000)

Thats it, Browse "localhost:8000/about/" in your browser (Assuming you have extended the flatpage in you app  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I had another source of this error.
The problem was saving the flatpages url without leading slash.

The view that throws this error changes the url if it hasn't a leading slash
So when i store 'example/' to db.

```py
# This is the view function where the error occurs.
# I stored 'example/' as url to db.
def flatpage(request, url):
    if not url.startswith('/'):
        # Here the url is manipulated and becomes '/example/':
        url = '/' + url 
    site_id = get_current_site(request).id
    try:
        # '/example/' does not exist in db:
        f = get_object_or_404(FlatPage, url=url, sites=site_id)
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32837#ticket